# Journey won't stop playing! (Changing Embed Object's Values With JQuery Doesn't Change Playing Video)

Tags: jquery, object, video, embed

I have a page with the following video player:

```
<div id="flashContent"> 
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="589" height="470" id="Take5" align="middle"> 
                <param name="movie" value="DontStopBelievin.swf" id="ee1" /> 
                <param name="quality" value="high" /> 
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#f7f7f7" /> 
                <param name="play" value="true" /> 
                <param name="loop" value="true" /> 
                <param name="wmode" value="window" /> 
                <param name="scale" value="showall" /> 
                <param name="menu" value="true" /> 
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" /> 
                <param name="salign" value="" /> 
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" /> 
                <!--[if !IE]>--> 
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="DontStopBelievin.swf" width="589" height="470" id="ininplay"> 
                    <param name="movie" value="DontStopBelievin.swf" id="ee2" /> 
                    <param name="quality" value="high" /> 
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#f7f7f7" /> 
                    <param name="play" value="true" /> 
                    <param name="loop" value="true" /> 
                    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /> 
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" /> 
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" /> 
                    <param name="menu" value="true" /> 
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" /> 
                    <param name="salign" value="" /> 
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" /> 
                <!--<![endif]--> 
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash"> 
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /> 
                    </a> 
                <!--[if !IE]>--> 
                </object> 
                <!--<![endif]--> 
            </object> 
        </div>
```

And links with onclick functions which call:

```
function changeMedia(id) {
    $('object#ininplay').attr('data', id + ".swf");     
    $('param#ee1').attr('value', id + ".swf");      
    $('param#ee2').attr('value', id + ".swf");      
}
```

This works great in that when I use Chrome's *Inspect Element* tool I can see that the aforementioned values have been changed to a valid and different file, and yet the original movie just keeps on playing...

I've listened to Don't Stop Believing thirteen times now on loop.

Comment: This is a non issue, why would you ever want that song to stop playing?

Comment: Don't worry there's no Stop button, I just wanted to give the user the option of switching between Don't Stop Believing and Wheel In The Sky (it's a suicide hotline website). Also if anyone knows how I can loop both songs at once please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply setting different parameter values for the embedded object data does not mean the flash player will re-evaluate them.
Your values are indeed being changed, but the embedded flash player simply ignores them after it has loaded.

You could try removing the entire 'flashcontent' div and replacing it with a new one.

You can easily do this with swfObject

[which you can get and read about here](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/)

... or you could use 
[jQuery's templating plugin](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/)